# Is there a way to read SMS using expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

Basically I want to get an event that the message has been received and send that message to my database (database bit already works)

I've tried all npm solutions including react-native-android-sms-listener, react-native-get-sms-android and other, but none seem to work, I've read somewhere, that expo may not support sms reading, but don't know how to use anything else for this sort of task

Comment: Look at https://forums.expo.io/t/how-we-can-read-sms-from-inbox-expo/13455

Answer (score 1):

Nope, It is not available for now in **expo** variant, regarding **Bare Workflow**, there are few solutions that helps in reading the SMS